# How to make a message repeat

Tags: lua

I'm making a code just to test some things out

```
print('Hello! What is your name?')
name = io.read()
print('Hello '..name..'!')

repeat
    print('What does a mute person say?')
    say = io.read()
    x = 'Nothing'
    z = 'nothing'
    if say == x then
        print('Correct!')
    elseif say == z then
        print('Correct!')
    else
        print('Incorrect! Guess Again!')
    end
until say = x or z
```

Everything works fine when I test it but if the answer is incorrect you cant try to answer again. Probably a stupid question but, is there anyway to make the question repeat when the answer is incorrect?

Comment: I don't know Lua, but that loop condition looks wrong...shouldn't it be something more like `until say == x or say == z` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop condition `say = x or z` shouldn't compile, use `==` to test equality, not `=`.

That's not enough, `say == x or z` is equivalent to `say == x` because `x or z` has the value of `x` if `x` is not `nil` or `false`.

```
repeat
    -- read say
until say == x or say == z
```